# Can create more than one table automatically?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating a music site. On this site I made relationships between the tables: albums, bands and "musics".
This "musics" ***table is automatically created*** with the album name when I add a song to the album like:
[allhopeisgone Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlQyO.png)

But, it creates only one table automatically. Can be more than one automatically?

Here is my code:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'datamusic');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $id    = $_GET['id'];
    $Music = $_POST['Music'];


    $sqlName = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE idAlbums='$id';";

    $queryName = mysqli_query($db, $sqlName);


    $Album;
    $bandId;
    $idAlbum;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryName)) {
        $Album   = $row['Album'];
        $bandId  = $row['albumId'];
        $idAlbum = $row['idAlbums'];

        if (preg_match('/\s/', $Album)) {
            $Album = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $Album);
            $sql   = "CREATE TABLE `datamusic`.`$Album` (
                      `idMusic` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      `Music` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
                      `bandId` INT NULL,
                      `albumId` INT NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY (`idMusic`),
                      INDEX `albumId_idx` (`albumId` ASC),
                      INDEX `bandId_idx` (`bandId` ASC),
                      CONSTRAINT `albumId`
                        FOREIGN KEY (`albumId`)
                        REFERENCES `datamusic`.`albums` (`idAlbums`)
                        ON DELETE NO ACTION
                        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
                      CONSTRAINT `bandId`
                        FOREIGN KEY (`bandId`)
                        REFERENCES `datamusic`.`bands` (`idBand`)
                        ON DELETE NO ACTION
                        ON UPDATE NO ACTION);";

            mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            $sqlNewMusic = "INSERT INTO $Album  VALUES(null,'$Music','$bandId','$idAlbum');";
            mysqli_query($db, $sqlNewMusic);

        }


        else {
            $sql = "CREATE TABLE `datamusic`.`$Album` (
                  `idMusic` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  `Music` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
                  `bandId` INT NULL,
                  `albumId` INT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY (`idMusic`),
                  INDEX `albumId_idx` (`albumId` ASC),
                  INDEX `bandId_idx` (`bandId` ASC),
                  CONSTRAINT `albumId`
                    FOREIGN KEY (`albumId`)
                    REFERENCES `datamusic`.`albums` (`idAlbums`)
                    ON DELETE NO ACTION
                    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
                  CONSTRAINT `bandId`
                    FOREIGN KEY (`bandId`)
                    REFERENCES `datamusic`.`bands` (`idBand`)
                    ON DELETE NO ACTION
                    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);";

            mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            $sqlNewMusic = "INSERT INTO $Album  VALUES(null,'$Music','$bandId','$idAlbum');";
            mysqli_query($db, $sqlNewMusic);

        }

    }

    header(" Location: editAlbum.php?id=$id");

}
```

Comment: $id will change the table name, which would make it different.

Comment: before you go any further with this project and you intend on going online with this; I suggest you **STOP right there** and start using a prepared statement. You **WILL BE HACKED** if you continue using this. You'll also save yourself a lot of time.

Comment: I'm creating just for experience, that isn't  really to be hosted online :)

Comment: Do not create a table per album, you just get the wrong experience.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to create tables on the fly like that. You should script up your DB so that you can publish it on every new environment. beyond that you should just be inserting/updating/deleting rows when the application is in use.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with nitsram, (and all the above)  Create your tables in MYSQL and then use your code to update and edit.  You would not want a separate table for each album that would result in many tables only containing one row.  Instead create a table called music where it holds columns like Album, Artist, Song...